# Convert a dict to numpy multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a python dictionary defined as follows, where the innermost items are two-element array:

```
    mydict = {1: {1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4]}, 2: {1: [5, 6], 2: [7, 8]}}
```

What I need now is to form all the 0th elements as a new array, i.e., using a[:,:,0] or a[...,0] to return [1,3,5,6]. However, a[:,:,0] or a[...,0] would not work in this case as shown below.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    a = np.array(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict))
    print a
```

which gives the following output:

```
    [[[1, 2] [5, 6]]
     [[3, 4] [7, 8]]]
```

It seems that this is an 2x2x2 array. There is no problem with accessing the corresponding element using separate brackets, e.g., a[0][0][0] returns 1. However, a[0,0,0] would cause an error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-150-f68aba7de42a> in <module>()
    ----> 1 a[0,0,0]

    IndexError: too many indices for array
```

It seems that the two-element arrays are considered as elements in the 2x2 array -- but what I need is a 2x2x2 array in order to achieve my goal. Is there any way to convert this to a 2x2x2 array?

Comment: @trincot, I think you're confused.  `a` is 3D numpy array, where `a[0,0,0]` would be perfectly valid if the inner most elements weren't list types.  `a[0,0][0]` works, for example.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, @wflynny!

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you ask for a result like `[1,3,5,6]`, but then you ask a 2x2x2 array. Which do you want?

Comment: Don't just guess about shape.  Print `a.shape` and `a.dtype`.  The commas, present or not are a clue.  Arrays format without comma, lists with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that pandas is treating your initial entries (lists) as objects, so then when you convert to a numpy array, your inner most entries are list objects.  For example,

```
> type(a)
numpy.ndarray
> type(a[0])
numpy.ndarray
> type(a[0,0])
list
```

If you know the shape you ultimately want (2x2x2), you could always do:

```
> b = np.array(map(np.array, a.flat)).reshape(2,2,2)
> b.shape
(2, 2, 2)
> b[0,0,0]
1
```

Edit:  Or even simpler:

```
> b = np.array(a.tolist())
array([[[1, 2],
        [5, 6]],

       [[3, 4],
        [7, 8]]])
```

If you want the first item of each innermost row, e.g. 1,3,5,7, you could do `b[...,0]` or `b[...,0].flatten()` depending on the resulting shape you want.

Comment: Or using stack operations : `np.hstack(np.hstack(a))` if you want to avoid mapping or creating a list.

Answer (score 2):

Without Pandas I can recreate your array with:

```
In [1723]: mydict = {1: {1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4]}, 2: {1: [5, 6], 2: [7, 8]}}
In [1724]: mydict
Out[1724]: {1: {1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4]}, 2: {1: [5, 6], 2: [7, 8]}}
In [1725]: mydict[1]
Out[1725]: {1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4]}
In [1726]: mydict[2]
Out[1726]: {1: [5, 6], 2: [7, 8]}
In [1727]: a=np.empty((2,2),dtype=object)
In [1728]: for i in range(2):
      ...:     for j in range(2):
      ...:         a[i,j]=mydict[i+1][j+1]
      ...:         
In [1729]: a
Out[1729]: 
array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
       [[5, 6], [7, 8]]], dtype=object)
In [1730]: print(a)
[[[1, 2] [3, 4]]
 [[5, 6] [7, 8]]]
```

This last print is the same as yours.

Elements of this array are lists

```
In [1735]: a[0,1]
Out[1735]: [3, 4]
In [1736]: type(a[0,1])
Out[1736]: list
```

The easist way to turn this into a 3d array is with `tolist`:

```
In [1737]: a.tolist()
Out[1737]: [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
In [1738]: np.array(a.tolist())
Out[1738]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
In [1739]: _.shape
Out[1739]: (2, 2, 2)
# dtype('int32')
```

`tolist` unpacks the array into a nested list; `np.array` then creates the highest-dimension array it can from that list structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig into each dictionary element, and then into each sub-dictionary, and pull out the first element of each of the leaf lists.

```
a = [mydict[x][y][0] for y in mydict[x] for x in mydict]
```

Result as a Python list:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

I believe this is what you actually want.

Comment: I think the OP wants to use pandas / numpy. Note that your solution doesn't preserve order. Here's a version that does: `[mydict[k0][k1][0] for k0 in sorted(mydict.keys()) for k1 in sorted(mydict[k0].keys())]`

Comment: It's a vanilla dict, which has no inherent order.  Still, your code is a good addition.  Also, I used the list to illustrate; OP already showed s/he knows how to convert to numpy.

Comment: Sure, a plain dict has no inherent order (although dict in Python 3.6 does actually preserve order), however, this particular dict (and its sub-dicts) is using numeric keys & I'm assuming the OP would like to use numeric ordering of those keys.